# Matrix derivative of $X^TY^TYX$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I am trying to calculate the following derivative, involving $X$ and $Y$ matrices:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial X}X^TY^TYX
$$

I have tried something similar to the approach in [Vector derivation of $x^Tx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132415/vector-derivation-of-xtx)

and end up with something like:

$$
X^TY^TYX + \mathbf{X^TY^TYZ + Z^TY^TYX + Z^TY^TYZ}
$$

I don't really know if I can consider $Z=I$ as in the link above.

Is there an easy way of calculating this derivative?

Something easier than calculating the per-entry derivative of the final matrix and reconstruct it using matrix operations.

Comment: Your result derivative is a fourth-rank tensor. It is hard to find a representation using standard matrices. And no, $Z$ is not $I$.

Answer (score 1):

I find it the most easy to solve this kind of questions explicitly in components. Let us agree on the [Einstein summation convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) that indices which appear double are summed over. Then
$$(X^T Y^T Y X)_{ij} = (X^T)_{ik} (Y^T)_{kl} Y_{lm} X_{mj}
=X_{ki} Y_{lk} Y_{lm} X_{mj}. $$
The elementary rule of taking the derivative with respect to the matrix $X_{ab}$ is
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial X_{ab}} X_{ij} = \delta_{ai} \delta_{bj}$$
with $\delta$ the [Kronecker symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta).

So we have
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial X_{ab}} (X^T Y^T Y X)_{ij}
=\frac{\partial}{\partial X_{ab}}  X_{ki} Y_{lk} Y_{lm} X_{mj}
= \delta_{ak} \delta_{bi} Y_{lk} Y_{lm} X_{mj} + \delta_{am} \delta_{bj}   X_{ki} Y_{lk} Y_{lm} \\
= \delta_{bi} Y_{la} Y_{lm} X_{mj}+  \delta_{bj}   X_{ki} Y_{lk} Y_{la}.$$

Written more compactly, we have
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial X_{ab}} (X^T Y^T Y X)_{ij} = (Y^T Y X)_{aj} \delta_{bi} + (X^T Y^T Y)_{ia} \delta_{bj}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let be $A = Y^TY$ and $H$ a "small" matrix:
$$
(X+H)^TA(X+H) - X^TAX = (X^T+H^T)A(X+H) - X^TAX = (X^TAH + H^TAX) + H^TAH
$$
The linear part is the term $X^TAH + H^TAX = X^TY^TYH + H^TY^TYX$. So, the differential of
$$X\mapsto X^TY^TYX$$
at $X = X_0$ is the linear function
$$H\mapsto X_0^TY^TYH + H^TY^TYX_0.$$